Trying to Handle Circular Dependencies and Memoization in React using Suspense
In my React app, I have some components that have circular dependencies and use React.Suspense for data fetching, trying to implement memoization for these async operations....What can I do to manage state and avoid infinite loops?
This is my code:
const fetchDataA = async (param) => {/* async logic */};
const fetchDataB = async (paramA) => {/* async logic */};

const ComponentA = ({ param }) => {
    const dataA = useFetch(fetchDataA, param);
    return <div>{dataA}</div>;
};

const ComponentB = ({ paramA }) => {
    const dataB = useFetch(fetchDataB, paramA);
    return <div>{dataB}</div>;
};

const ParentComponent = () => {
    const [param, setParam] = useState("initial");
    return (
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
            <ComponentA param={param} />
            <ComponentB paramA={param} />
            <button onClick={() => setParam("updated")}>Update Param</button>
        </Suspense>
    );
};


